# Omitting date from label text, only showing time

Tags: c#, datetime

The following code displays the label as `Planning horizon: 20/11/2014 08:00:00 to 20/11/2014 09:00:00`, how do I get it to display it as `Planning horizon: 08:00:00 to 09:00:00`.

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Parse("08:00:00");
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Parse("09:00:00");

label1.Text = "Planning horizon: " + startTime + " to "  + endTime;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just format your `DateTime`'s with `.ToString()` method like;

```
label1.Text = "Planning horizon: " + startTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + " to "  
               + endTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

#### Long Answer

Since you using `string + DateTime` concatenation, this process will call `string + object` overload and uses `.ToString()` method for the second parameter.

From [`DateTime.ToString()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> The value of the current DateTime object is formatted using the
>   [general date and time format specifier (`'G'`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime).
>
> This method uses formatting information derived from the current
>   culture. In particular, it combines the custom format strings returned
>   by the [`ShortDatePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`LongTimePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longtimepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties of the
>   DateTimeFormatInfo object returned by the
>   CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat property

And looks like your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s `ShortDatePattern` and `LongTimePattern` is `dd/MM/yyyy` and `HH:mm:ss`. That's why you get string result based these concated formats.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.ToLongTimeString()` or `.ToShortTimeString()` on your `DateTime`s.

```
  DateTime x = DateTime.Now;
  Console.WriteLine(x.ToLongTimeString());
  Console.WriteLine(x.ToShortTimeString());
```

Will Generate:

```
9:30:20 AM
9:30 AM
```

For your specific output you may want to customize the output string, so instead do this:

```
startTime.ToString("HH:mm:ss")
```

Which outputs (note the `HH` outputs in a 24 hour clock):

```
09:30:14
```

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more info on formatting time strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use the TimeOfDay function.  See the link below for formatting options.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I don't think `TimeOfDay` is a good option in such a case because it _might_ generate `AM/PM` designator as a result as well.

Comment: Provided the correct formatting option you can omit the am/pm designator.